# How to replace words in specific column using mysql?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a table `myspec` with record like below. It has more than 100 records. I want to replace based on some condition. How do I replace words inside a string in MYSQL?

`id` definition:

```
1  <id>1234</id>
   <name>sbc</name>
   <spec class = "com.fs.one">
     <x class = "">
     </x>
    <y class = "">
     </y>
   </spec>

2  <id>890</id>
   <name>test</name>
   <spec class = "com.fs.five">
     <x class = "">
         <x class = "">
         </x>
         <y class = "">
         </y>
     </x>
   </spec>
```

How do I replace `<spec...> </spec>` with my new value `@newdefinition`?

```
@newdefinition  = "<spec class = "com.fs.new"> 
                    <x class = "">
                        <x>
                        </x>
                        <y>
                        </y>
                    </x>
                    <y>
                    </y>"
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? If you're using 8.0 you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: How to do that? coz we have specs value with different

Comment: Replace the regular expression `<spec[\s\S]*</spec>` with `@newdefinition`

Comment: That's the whole point of using a regular expression. You use a wildcard for the variable part.